# I want to find the xpath for the image

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, html-parsing

This is the html code

```
<div class="navBg">
<table id="topnav" class="navTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="-moz-user-        select: none; cursor: default;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="logoCell" valign="top">
<td class="separator">
<td class="navItem relative" style="z-index: 99">
<td class="separator">
<td class="navItem relative">
<a class="content tasks" style="border-width: 0" href="/tasks/otasklist.do">
<div class="label" style="z-index:155; ">Tasks</div>
<img class="sizer" width="84" height="93" src="/img/default/pixel.gif? hash=1106906246"/>
<span class="bottomBorder">
```

I am trying to find the xpath for the image-->

```
src="/img/default/pixel.gif?hash=1106906246"
```

I have tried different combinations e:g

```
//table/tbody/tr/td[5][@class='navItem relative']/a/div[2]/img
```

I have written the following code too.

```
 WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Tasks")));

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[5][@class='navItem relative']/a/div[2]/img")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

It's identifying the element on web page by firepath but after running the script it's not clicking on the element and the console shows "No Such Element Exception".

Please answer in java lang only.
Can somebody please help me out.???

Thx

Comment: Should it not just be `//table/tbody/tr/td[5]/a/img` ? Why the `div`?

Comment: I used this..and it worked  //td[@class='navItem relative']/a[@class='content tasks_selected selected']/div/img"

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using Selenium. The safest bet is to find the closest parent with an `@id` attribute, and work your way down from there. Try this: `//table[@id='topnav']//img`. As alecxe pointed out, depending on how unique the image is in this table, you may need to narrow the XPath down a little more. Something like `//table[@id='topnav']//tr[1]//img`, or even `//table[@id='topnav']//td[contains(@class, 'navItem')]//img`.

The XPath you posted will not work, as it has some problems compared to the sample HTML you posted:

1. `tbody` may not appear in all browsers
2. the qualifier `[@class='navItem relative']` for the element `td[5]` is redundant (although this is not exactly a problem)
3. `div[2]` does not exists, your HTML sample shows only one `div`

Comment: Hi SiKing..the html part is holding 2 div s from which i have posted the div part that i wanted to use to trace the element.

Comment: If you do not post the complete HTML block, then it is difficult to answer with a correct XPath. Do any of my suggestions above work for you? If yes, then vote my reply as the valid answer. If not, clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to find the `img` tag. Depending on the uniqueness of the `img` tag attributes and it's location on the page.

Here's one way to find it, based on the `Tasks` div:

```
//table//div[text()='Tasks']/following-sibling::img
```

You can also rely on the `td` in which the `img` is located and check for the `sizer` class:

```
//table//td[contains(@class, 'navItem')]/img[@class='sizer']
```

And so on.

Comment: Thanks alecxe...i'll definitely use this approach